# Can I use headphone port as Aux input?

Tags: music

I recently moved house and I found a music system. Its called philips C170 mini hifi system: it has 3cd system and to this 2 speakers are connected through 2 wires. For the speakers to be connected there's 4 port for the wire to be plugged in; old fashioned type but it has decent sound quality when I use it on radio and apart from a headphone jack there isn't any port for Aux input or mobile phone to connect. Can I use the headphone jack as a Aux input? Urgent!!!

Comment: No. Headphone would be output and not input. If it doesn't have any input ports that are labeled you won't be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.
The Headphone Jack is designed as an output only.  See Page 14 of the [User Manual](http://download.p4c.philips.com/files/f/fwc170_22/fwc170_22_dfu_eng.pdf).  This unit looks like it will mute the speakers if a pair of headphones is detected, so I would expect even if you could hack a way to reroute the jack, the tip switch would still turn off the speakers.

I'd recommend using an [AUX to Tape Adapter](https://www.walmart.com/ip/RCA-Cassette-Adapter/16553075).  These tend to have ok sound quality (equivalent to FM but below CD to my ears) and are available at almost every electronics store, and most mobile phone shops as well.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yup. +1. those things are awful, but the only way. *Note:* if it sounds dull & fuzzy, stop playback, eject & try again. 3 times out of 10 they line up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**No you cannot.**

Two things:

1. You said it yourself, "old fashioned".
2. The headphone jack is only output.
3. Unless there is a AUX jack, no other input mode can be used as a substitute.

P.S.
I know how you feel, sometimes when you find something cool and want to listen to music but there is a problem that stands in your way ;)

Cheers!